# Scrapy Torproject

Tags: scrapy, tor

On Ubuntu,

```
[guy@guy-laptop tmp]$ sudo /etc/init.d/tor status
tor is running
[guy@guy-laptop tmp]$ sudo /etc/init.d/polipo start
Starting polipo: /usr/bin/polipo already running -- doing nothing
polipo.
```

also:

```
$ python -c 'import urllib; print urllib.getproxies()'
{'ftp': 'ftp://127.0.0.1:8118/', 'all': 'socks://127.0.0.1:8118/',
'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8118/', 'https': 'https://127.0.0.1:8118/',
'no': 'localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local'}
```

When running scrapy I get:

> ERROR: Error downloading https://registration.example.com/login.fcc:
>   [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): : [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake
>   failure')]
>          ]

While on the same time FireFox managed to get the page correctly
through proxy

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running the script through proxychains?  To install on ubuntu:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install proxychains
```

then configure the /etc/proxychains.conf file to work with TOR (socks4/5).

> ```
> # defaults set to "tor"
> ```
>
> socks4   127.0.0.1 9050

Then you can run anything though TOR

```
:~$ proxychains scriptwhatever.py target
```

Once you know TOR is working correctly, I recommend quiet mode in the proxychains.conf file.

> # Quiet mode (no output from library).
>     quiet_mode